# "ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated"

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle

Fala galera, bom dia, estou com um código legado e estou tendo a seguinte dificuldade:

Quando tento verificar alguma palavra que tenha aspa simples eu recebo esse erro `ORA-01756`

**Ex: raphael me'lo**

agora quando tento:

**Ex: raphael me''lo**

não recebo o tal erro, porém não estou conseguindo entender onde ele esta fazendo a tal verificação:

segue a linha de código:

**palavras-indevidas.model.js**:

```js
'use strict';

class PalavrasIndevidas {
    constructor(listaPalavrasIndevidas = []) {
        this.listaPalavrasIndevidas = listaPalavrasIndevidas;
    }
}

try { module.exports = exports = PalavrasIndevidas } 
catch (e) { exports = PalavrasIndevidas }
```

**palavras-indevidas.service.js**:

```js
'use strict';

// constants
const routeCreator = require('../../../../../common/route-creator')();

// support methods
const SuporteOperacoes = require(`${config.paths.app}/comum/suporte.operacoes`);

// repository patterns
const PalavrasIndevidasRepository = require('./palavras-indevidas.persistence');

// model domains
const PalavrasIndevidas = require('./palavras-indevidas.model');

class PalavrasIndevidasService {
     constructor(appContext, httpOptions) {
        this._context = appContext;
        this._options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(httpOptions));

        let servicePath = `${httpOptions.getLocalPathPBase()}/sistema/palavras-indevidas`;
        let palavrasIndevidasRepository = new PalavrasIndevidasRepository();

        this._getPalavrasIndevidas = (req, res) => {
   let palavrasIndevidas = new PalavrasIndevidas();
   //var palavrasIndevidas = null;
   
   //palavrasIndevidas = req.query;
   if(typeof req.query.listaPalavrasIndevidas == "string") palavrasIndevidas.listaPalavrasIndevidas = [req.query.listaPalavrasIndevidas];
   if(req.query.listaPalavrasIndevidas instanceof Array) palavrasIndevidas.listaPalavrasIndevidas = req.query.listaPalavrasIndevidas;
   //let palavrasIndevidas = req.body

   palavrasIndevidasRepository.listarPalavrasIndevidas(palavrasIndevidas, lista => {
    res.send( lista );
    res.end();
   });
  };

        this._postPalavrasIndevidas = (req, res) => {
   palavrasIndevidasRepository.manterPalavrasIndevidas(req.body, mensagemRetorno => {
    res.send(SuporteOperacoes.deParaMensagemDB(mensagemRetorno));
    res.end();
   });
  };

        this._verificarPalavraIndevida= (req, res) => {
            global.log.info(__filename.split('/').reverse()[0]+' \nVerificar Palavras indevidas', req.query);
            let txt = httpOptions.mapObject(req);
            console.log(txt);
            

            var array = [];

            let textoDecodificado = decodeURIComponent(txt.texto);

            array = textoDecodificado.split(" ");
            
            palavrasIndevidasRepository.palavrasEncontradas(array, res, (lista) => {
                res.send(lista);
                res.end();
            });
        }
        
  routeCreator.bind(this._context, this._options.verbEnum.GET, servicePath, this._getPalavrasIndevidas);

        routeCreator.bind(this._context, this._options.verbEnum.POST, `${servicePath}/ope`, this._postPalavrasIndevidas);
     
        routeCreator.bind(this._context, this._options.verbEnum.GET, servicePath + "/validar-texto", this._verificarPalavraIndevida);

    }
}

module.exports = exports = PalavrasIndevidasService;
```

**palavras-indevidas.persistence.js**:

```js
'use strict';

// libs
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

// common
const dbEngine = new require('../../../../../common/database-connector')();
const dbConstants = require('../../../../../common/database-constants');

// model domains
const Mensagem = require('../../comum/mensagem.model');
const Motivo = require('../../comum/motivo.model');
const Situacao = require('../../comum/situacao.model');
const Registro = require('../../comum/registro.model');
const PalavrasIndevidas = require('./palavras-indevidas.model');
let SbeUtil = require('../../../../../common/sbe-util');

const c_COMMAND_LISTAR = "BEGIN :cursor := SBE.KSBE_PARAMETRIZACAO_PORTAL.LISTAR_PALAVRA_INDEVIDA(p_lst_palavra_indevida => :p_lst_palavra_indevida); END;";
const c_COMMAND_MANTER = "SBE.KSBE_PARAMETRIZACAO_PORTAL.manter_palavra_indevida(p_lst_palavra_indevida, :p_msg_sistemica); END;";
const c_COMMAND_VALIDAR = " v_Return := SBE.KSBE_PARAMETRIZACAO_PORTAL.listar_palavra_indevida(p_lst_palavra_indevida => p_lst_palavra_indevida); :cursor := v_Return; END;";

class PalavrasIndevidasRepository {
    listarPalavrasIndevidas (palavrasIndevidas, callback) {

  if(!palavrasIndevidas.listaPalavrasIndevidas instanceof Array){
   callback(new Mensagem(null, '10', 'parâmetro inválido - listaPalavrasIndevidas', new Date(), null, null));
   return false;
  }
  
  if(palavrasIndevidas.listaPalavrasIndevidas.length == 0){
   callback(new Mensagem(null, '10', 'parâmetro inválido - listaPalavrasIndevidas', new Date(), null, null));
   return false;
  }
  
        const bindVars = {
   p_lst_palavra_indevida: { val: palavrasIndevidas.listaPalavrasIndevidas, type: oracledb.DB_TYPE_CLOB, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN },
   cursor: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 2 }   
        };

        try 
  {
   //global.log.info(__filename+" sqlCommand: " + c_COMMAND_LISTAR);
   //global.log.info(__filename+" body: "+ JSON.stringify(palavrasIndevidas));
   dbEngine.execute(c_COMMAND_LISTAR, dbConstants.PROC_OUT, bindVars, callbackDB);
        } 
  catch (error) 
  {
          global.log.error(__filename.split('/').reverse()[0]+' \nlistarPalavrasIndevidas', error);
          callback(new Mensagem(null, '10', 'Erro na execução do serviço', new Date(), null, null));
        }

        function callbackDB(connection, resultSet, numRows) {
   let objRetorno = new PalavrasIndevidas();
   try
   {
    resultSet.getRows( // get numRows rows
     numRows,
     function (err, rows) 
     {
      if (err) 
      {
       global.log.error(__filename.split('/').reverse()[0]+' \nPalavrasIndevidasRepository.listarPalavrasIndevidas.callbackDB', err);
       dbEngine.doClose(connection, resultSet); // always close the result set
       callback(new Mensagem(null, '10', 'Erro na execução do serviço', new Date(), null, null));
       return false;
      } 
      else if (rows.length === 0) 
      {    // no rows, or no more rows
       callback(new Mensagem(null, '8', 'Não há registro retornado na pesquisa.', new Date(), null, null));
       dbEngine.doClose(connection, resultSet); // always close the result set
       return false;
      } else if (rows.length > 0) 
      {
       for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
       {
        var strPalavraIndevida = rows[i][0];
        objRetorno.listaPalavrasIndevidas.push(strPalavraIndevida);
       }
       dbEngine.doClose(connection, resultSet); // always close the result set
       callback(objRetorno);
       return true;
      }
     }
    );
   }
   catch(error)
   {
    global.log.error(__filename.split('/').reverse()[0]+' \nlistarPalavrasIndevidas', error);
    callback(new Mensagem(null, '10', 'Erro na execução do serviço', new Date(), null, null));
    return false;
   }
   return true;
        }    
    }

    manterPalavrasIndevidas (palavrasIndevidas, callback) {

     let itemMapArr = [];
     palavrasIndevidas.listaPalavrasIndevidas.forEach((item) => {
            itemMapArr.push("'" + item + "'");
        });
     
     let listaSQL = SbeUtil.convertArrayToPlSql(itemMapArr, 'p_lst_palavra_indevida');

        let sqlAction = "DECLARE p_lst_palavra_indevida SBE.KSBE_PARAMETRIZACAO_PORTAL.LISTA_PALAVRA_INDEVIDA_TYPE; BEGIN "
            + listaSQL + " " + c_COMMAND_MANTER;
     
        const bindVars = {
            p_msg_sistemica:  { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT }
        };

        try { 
   global.log.info(__filename+" sqlCommand: " + sqlAction);
   global.log.info(__filename+" bindVars: "+ JSON.stringify(bindVars));   
            dbEngine.execute(sqlAction, dbConstants.MERGE, bindVars, callbackDB);
        }
        catch (error) {

            global.log.error(__filename.split('/').reverse()[0]+' \nmanterPalavrasIndevidas', error);
   
            callback(new Mensagem(null, '10', 'Erro na execução do serviço', new Date(), null, null));
        }

        function callbackDB(connection, result, mensagemRetorno) {
            try {
                if (mensagemRetorno.codigo === 0) {
                    mensagemRetorno.codigo = result.p_msg_sistemica;
                } else 
    {
                    mensagemRetorno.mensagem = 'Erro na execução do serviço';
                }

                dbEngine.doRelease(connection);
                callback(mensagemRetorno);
            } catch (err) {
                global.log.error(__filename.split('/').reverse()[0]+' \nmanterPalavrasIndevidas.callbackDB', err);
                callback(new Mensagem(null, '10', 'Erro na execução do serviço', new Date(), null, null));
            }
        }
    }

 palavrasEncontradas(listaPalavras, res, callback) {
        let palavrasIndevidasEncontradas = [];
        
        var bindVars = null;
        var bindVars = {
            cursor: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR, maxSize: 2 }
        };

        let itemMapArr = [];
        listaPalavras.forEach((item) => {
            itemMapArr.push("'" + item + "'");
        });

        let listaSQL = SbeUtil.convertArrayToPlSql(itemMapArr, 'p_lst_palavra_indevida');

        let sqlAction = "DECLARE p_lst_palavra_indevida SBE.KSBE_PARAMETRIZACAO_PORTAL.LISTA_PALAVRA_INDEVIDA_TYPE; v_Return SYS_REFCURSOR; BEGIN "
            + listaSQL + " " + c_COMMAND_VALIDAR;
        try {
            dbEngine.execute(sqlAction, dbConstants.SELECT, bindVars, callbackDB, false, true);
        } catch (error) {
            global.log.error(__filename.split('/').reverse()[0]+' \npalavrasEncontradas', error);
            res.status(422);
            callback(
                new Mensagem(null, '10', 'Erro na execução do serviço', new Date(), "palavrasEncontradas", null)
            );
        }

        function callbackDB(connection, resultSet, numRows) {
            global.log.info(__filename.split('/').reverse()[0]+' \nno metodo callbackDB');
            try {
                resultSet.getRows( // get numRows rows
                    numRows,
                    function (err, rows) {
                        if (err) {
                            global.log.error(__filename.split('/').reverse()[0]+' \npalavrasEncontradas.callbackDB', err);
                            global.log.error(err, numRows);
                            callback(
                                new Mensagem(null, '10', 'testinho mais top ainda', new Date(), 'palavrasEncontradas.callbackDB', { err: err, oracleErro: numRows })
                            );
                        } else if (rows.length === 0) { // no rows, or no more rows
                            callback(palavrasIndevidasEncontradas);
                            dbEngine.doClose(connection, resultSet); // always close the result set
                        } else if (rows.length > 0) {
                            palavrasIndevidasEncontradas = rows.map((row) => row.DE_PALAVRA_INDEVIDA);
                            callbackDB(connection, resultSet, numRows);
                        }
                    });
            } catch (e) {
                global.log.error(__filename.split('/').reverse()[0]+' \npalavrasEncontradas.callbackDB', numRows, e.stack);
                global.log.error(e);
                global.log.error(numRows);
                res.status(422);
                callback(
                    new Mensagem(null, numRows.codigo || '10', 'testinho top', new Date(), 'palavrasEncontradas.callbackDB', { javascriptErro: e.message, oracleErro: numRows })
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = exports = PalavrasIndevidasRepository;
```

Fico grato desde já.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O conteúdo entre aspas simples identifica que aquele dado é texto (para os bancos de dados), sendo assim, quando você tem algum texto que possua aspas simples, precisa adicionar o escape que é uma aspa simples a mais.

**Exemplo:**

```
--Nesse caso irá ocorrer o erro
INSERT INTO TABELA (ID, NOME) VALUES (1, 'Caixa d'água');

--Nesse caso irá funcionar
INSERT INTO TABELA (ID, NOME) VALUES (1, 'Caixa d''água');
```

Uma possível solução é você adicionar uma aspas simples a mais ou remover as aspas simples antes de enviar para seu repositório.

**Adicionar aspas simples**

```
// Vamos supor que esse seja seu campo de texto
var texto = "caixa d'água";

// Iremos substituir as aspas simples adicionando uma aspas a mais
texto = texto.replace(/'/g, "''");

// O resultado será "caixa d''água"
```

**Remover aspas simples**

```
// Vamos supor que esse seja seu campo de texto
var texto = "caixa d'água";

// Iremos remover as aspas simples do nosso campo
texto = texto.replace(/'/g, "");

// O resultado será "caixa dágua"
```

Comment: Entendi, mas supondo que esse valor verificado vem de um input no front, como que eu poderia adicionar essa outra aspa simples antes da verificação no back ? ou até mesmo remover a aspa simples na hora de enviar o dado ?

Comment: Tente com essa alteração da resposta

Comment: faz sentido, muito obrigado Pedro